# Stubborn decals on alloy rims

Tags: decals

I have a pair of SRAM Roam 50 wheels (like [this](https://www.theproscloset.com/products/sram-roam-50-alloy-tubeless-27-5-front-wheel)) with very excessive decals. I'm trying to remove them but no known method seems to work. The following methods have failed (= don't even scratch the surface):

- Heat Gun
- Plastic Razor
- Isopropyl alcohol
- WD40
- Any combination of the above

The only method that has (very little) success is an old school razor (metal) - but that scratches the rim.

Is it possible that there's a clear coat on top of these stickers?

Has anyone encountered such stubborn rim decals and won the war?

Comment: I have had great success on difficult things such as this with Eucalyptus oil, or a proprietary oil based solvent like "Desolve-it". Give them plenty of time to work - hours if needed. Being oil based they do not evaporate off.  Ultimately these decals are designed to outlast the aluminum they are stuck to.